# Spring Cloud Gateway not forwarding correctly

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Boot application that is attempting to use Spring Cloud Gateway to access some microservices. The code I am using is based on instructions read at:

```
https://betterjavacode.com/programming/how-to-use-api-gateway-with-spring-cloud
```

Basically, my application duplicates the code provided on that site, including the two test microservices
that the author created:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/vendor")
public class VendorController
{
    @GetMapping("/total")
    public List vendors()
    {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("CJI Consultants");
        list.add("Signature Consultants");
        list.add("Deloitte");
        return list;
    }
}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController
{
    @GetMapping("/total")
    public List customers()
    {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Microsoft");
        list.add("Amazon");
        list.add("Apple");
        return list;
    }
}
```

My actual gateway code is similar to the author's:

package com.betterjavacode.apigatewaydemo.config;

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig
{
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder)
    {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route("customerModule", rt -> rt.path("/customer/**")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/"))
                .route("vendorModule", rt -> rt.path("/vendor/**")
                    .uri("http://localhost:8082/"))
                    .build();

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this application, enter the correct URLs:

```
http://localhost:8080/vendor/total
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/customer/total
```

I get 404 errors!

The only way I seem able to access the two microservices through the gateway is to change the path to "/**".
For example, in order to access the customer microservice I have to change:

.route("customerModule", rt -> rt.path("/customer/**")
.uri("http://localhost:8081/"))

to

v.route("customerModule", rt -> rt.path("/**")
.uri("http://localhost:8081/"))

then I can see the customer microservice output without problems. Of course, I cannot use the same path for both routes. It looks like this gateway is only able to handle one route using the "/**" path.

Am I missing something here? Can someone give some idea of why this isn't working properly? How can I get this gateway to forward to the paths it should be going to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have resolved the problem. It turns out that, for reasons unknown, whenever a route other than "/**" is used in the Gateway, the URI must not contain the HTTP prefix.

In other words, instead of having a route:

```
route("customerModule", rt -> rt.path("/customer/**")
                    .uri("http://localhost:8081/"))
```

The route should be without the HTTP prefix:

```
.route("customerModule", rt -> rt.path("/customer/**")
                    .uri("localhost:8081/"))
```

I do not know why this works, but it does. I can access the microservices as long as I format the uri without the prefix.

I discovered this by accident. I would be curious to know why it works that way, but at least this requirement should be documented.

Comment: Have you figured out why this is happenig ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `StripPrefix` parameter.

```java
return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route("customerModule", rt -> rt.path("/customer/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(0))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/"))
                .route("vendorModule", rt -> rt.path("/vendor/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(0))
                    .uri("http://localhost:8082/"))
                    .build();
```

or you can remove the @RequestMapping("/customer") and @RequestMapping("/vendor") because it deletes the prefix path before sending it downstream.

Comment: Thanks fr the reply. I tried both approaches. Neither worked. Still getting 404 errors when attempting to access the microservices.